# Usb-c to HDMI adapter shows as billboard device - no display

Tags: usb, display, hdmi, asus, monitor

I've tried a few different adapters to get display output from my usb c port. None have worked on ubuntu. This is what I get (or similar) from `lsusb` for every hdmi-usbc adapter I buy:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:2172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. BillBoard Device
```

From what I can gather 'Billboard' just means that switching to alternate mode failed because of some issue.

In monitor settings, I only see the built-in monitor. Similarly, I installed ARandR no other outputs appear.

So,

## Adapter

I have tried a few adapters. The one I'm trying currently is 'plugable usb-c to hdmi adapter'. It is stated to support linux and any usb-c port that supports DisplayPort Alternate Mode. OK.

## Laptop

I have the ASUS C523N. It is stated to support driving a display from usb-c, but nothing more specific: [spec sheet](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/For-Work/Chromebook/ASUS-Chromebook-C523/techspec/).

This is a chromebook. When I boot into chrome-os, the display works through the same usb-c port.

## Other details

Kernel: `5.15.0-50-generic`

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep TYPEC_DP
CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m
```

Ubuntu: `22.04.1 LTS`

Dmesg:

```
[80603.451223] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[80603.610532] usb 1-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[80603.628180] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=2172, bcdDevice= 1.00
[80603.628202] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=17, Product=18, SerialNumber=19
[80603.628210] usb 1-2: Product: BillBoard Device
[80603.628217] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[80603.628223] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000
```

## Related issue

The only issue that I can find matching is this: [USB-C to HDMI not working on Dell XPS 13 9370](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157518/usb-c-to-hdmi-not-working-on-dell-xps-13-9370)

The solution there was just to try another adapter. I'm on my 3rd purchase and I can't always get returns. This one explicitly says it supports linux. I will try to contact their support and report back here. I really can't keep buying cables and hoping that it works. I'm looking to at least get a handle on what the problem is here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Almost same problem to me, but in Windows, i found article that explain something, maybe be can give a bit explanation

*"If you want to use a USB-C cable to connect two devices so one can output DisplayPort to a display, make sure that both support USB Power Delivery. Otherwise you’ll need to use an adapter to split/convert the USB-C plug into a DisplayPort connector."*

Refers from "https://stronglybranched.io/2020/01/usb-c-device-wont-output-to-a-usb-c-monitor"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1292890)